# Creating a second view and controller on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If my model has the following fields:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :title, :year, :month
  scope :recent, order('year desc, month desc').limit(3)
end
```

if I also want to view this data by year, is it better to create a new controller and view for year?  Or should I do this using routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing this by routes too, but despite of that, you don't need multiple controllers or views as you raised in your concern.
You can do this, by creating a collection route for `Book` in `routes.rb` as:

```
resources :books do
  get '/by/:timeline', to: 'books#timeline', as: 'timeline', on: :collection
end
```

This will provide you a GET `timeline_books_path`, which can be configured in `BooksController`'s `timeline` method.

Call like `timeline_books_path('months')` will make available the URI: `/books/by/months` and `params[:timeline]` will be equal to 'month' for your disposal at `timeline` method.
Similar is the case with `timeline_books_path('year')` => `/books/by/year`.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I wound up using timeline as a variable not the string you suggested, so you can do /books/by/2012 or /books/by/2012, etc.

Comment: That's a nice way. Giving you more flexibility; but then your controller logic just got more. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think by routes or query strings would be better, instead of several actions. Just send the response from one action according to different routes or params.

SO does the same(by route):

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

No, you should reuse the current view and controller. Easiest way would be to add a parameter to the `index` action:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:year]
      @books = Book.where(:year => params[:year])
    else
      @books = Book.scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Also, it might be a good idea to move this filter to the `Book` model. If you find yourself adding a lot of filters to this action, you can refactor the filtering logic to another class.